# Alter URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a *.htaccess* file inside folder `public` (root/public)

I would like to achieve the following transformations:

1. `/index.php` -> `/`
2. `index.php?site=siteName` -> `/siteName/`
3. `/siteName/` or `/siteName` -> `serves as ?site=siteName`

Here is my complete *.htaccess* file so far (with case 3 solved):

```
Allow from all

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?current=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?current=$1
```

Comment: Yes, one is example, and other is actual code used on my demo project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an additional rules for redirection of old URL to pretty URL and `index.php` removal:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?current=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?current=$1 [L,QSA]
```